# Equivalent (roughly) of setCurrent() in BlackBerry()

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, porting, cldc

Equivalent (roughly) of setCurrent() in BlackBerry()?

I have some J2ME code I am porting to BBs RIM classes. The J2ME code uses setCurrent() to "change page" in the application, but that is of course not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BlackBerry UI has the concept of *screens*:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( screen )
```

See the [UiApplication documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html).

Comment: Yes, but there seems to be a difference. With setCurrent() I can just paint any Displayable. Screens seem to be more of separate entities. Maybe the question should be, is there any Displayable equivalent in BB?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, so it's hard to answer. You can certainly subclass a Screen yourself and override the paint() method in it to do whatever painting you want.